# Custom Cursor - Trouble With Hover State

Tags: jquery, css

I'm creating a working prototype for a paint by numbers game. I thought it would be cool to replace the default cursor with a paintbrush, so I found some CSS and jQuery to do that for me. [Here is the prototype page.](http://www.tomryandesign.com/dev/paint/) All the CSS and jQuery will be visible in the source of that page.

The only remaining problem is that the hand cursor still appears when hovering over an `area` polygon, which the entire interface I've built depends on. Is there some selector or state I'm missing in my code to get the paintbrush "cursor" to work ALL the time?

Comment: Ditto.  What browser/OS are you having trouble in?

Comment: Same thing happens in Safari.

Comment: Nope, the !important tag doesn't fix it.

Answer (score 0):

What if you remove `pointer-events: none;` from the div with id "brush," and then use a transparent image for the pointer for that div?